# Can you say 'study a degree'?

Tags: grammar, phrases, word-usage, british-english, phrase-usage

I received an online promotion from the University of Edinburgh titled "Study a World-Class Degree Online."

It struck me as remarkably bad English coming from an institute, but in this case it comes from one of the established universities of the UK.

This makes me wonder: ***is "studying a degree" in common usage?***

Google returns an astounding  4,080,000 results for the phrase, even though the very top one is from WordReference questioning the usage (in 2008). The phrase "*study for  a degree*" returns  6,470,000, "*earn a degree*" gets about 8,000,000 and the humble "*get a degree*" beats all of them  41,300,000. 
There is some chance that the subject line was created by Coursera, but the phrase is repeated in the write-up.

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: Why is it remarkably bad English? And can you provide a link, please?

Comment: Researchers these days study anything and everything -- why not a certain degree somewhere? "study a * degree" gets me 42,50,00,000 hits.  But seriously, "She was awarded a Fulbright scholarship to study a degree in education and economics at Yale in 1954" (The Canberra Times)

Comment: Raw google result counts are notoriously unreliable. But ngrams suggest that the phrase exists, but is rarer than "study for": https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=study+a+degree%2Cstudy+for+a+degree&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cstudy%20a%20degree%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cstudy%20for%20a%20degree%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Related: [What's the correct way of saying that one is pursuing a degree?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/355154)

Comment: Some of the comments in the question linked by @sumelic suggest this might be a BrE thing; Google ngrams shows zero results for "study a degree" for British English.

Comment: p.s. It strikes me as unusually but not "remarkably bad"

Comment: @mari-lou-a -- I've never read that phrase in any formal setting, and only heard it spoken twice, at best. A link would probably not be possible as it is a mailer. I can try posting a screenshot. Bad English Because you can study a phenomenon, an insect, a subject, but not a degree, if I may.

Comment: @james-random Thanks a lot for the n-gram. I did try using n-gram earlier but I used " " and it did not work. The n-gram seems to show that whatever little purchase "study a study" had against "earn a degree" , it is losing fast.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the correct way of saying that one is pursuing a degree?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/355154/whats-the-correct-way-of-saying-that-one-is-pursuing-a-degree)

Comment: @iqbal-ahmed-siyal  I (the OP) already know the distinction. The question here is whether the phrase  has  become so 'mainstream'  now that a  communication from a reputed university would use this phrase, that too in its title .

Comment: *...one of the established universities of **England**?* Edinburgh is in ***Scotland**!*

Comment: @fumblefingers : Yes, I should have written UK

Comment: I'm primarily a Brit rather than an Englishman (as are the vast majority of my compatriots, however so defined! :), so it doesn't really bother me even though I can't help *noticing*. But most likely quite a few Scots would be a bit irked!

Comment: google: "study a degree" site:.uk returns 117,000 hits

Comment: It probably to some extent has to do with the way students in the UK enter University education compared with some other countries like the USA for example. Here in the UK a student will be given an offer to join a particular degree course at a certain establishment. They are at that university to study that degree, in America it is common for students to be admitted to the college as a whole ( there are some exceptions) where they can study different subjects as they choose.

Comment: Of course it's wrong, but so very sadly it's not "remarkably bad".

One does not study a degree; one studies *for* or *towards* a degree… but living up to that would require more qualifications than the relevant people possess.

Comment: Google result hits are basically meaningless for this application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Google Books search returns three confirmable matches for "study a degree " in the sense of "study for a degree"—all of them from 2005 or later. From Rosa M. Ros, "[Astronomy and Mathematics](https://books.google.com/books?id=Qr2J-iomErcC&pg=PA14&dq=%22study+a+degree%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwicn5aTtZPdAhWUITQIHb1vDIgQ6AEIUzAH#v=onepage&q=%22study%20a%20degree%22&f=false)," in Jay Pasachoff & John Percy, *Education, Teaching and Learning Astronomy: Effective Strategies for Educators* (Cambridge University Press, 2005):

> To educate society in astronomy it is necessary to teach astronomy at primary and secondary school. Students may then decide to study astronomy at university. It is hard to imagine students deciding to **study a degree** in a topic that they do not know.

From Tony Purvis, [*Get Set for Media and Cultural Studies*](https://books.google.com/books?id=Gc2qBgAAQBAJ&pg=PA50&dq=%22study+a+degree%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwicn5aTtZPdAhWUITQIHb1vDIgQ6AEIMzAC#v=onepage&q=%22study%20a%20degree%22&f=false) (Edinburgh University Press, 2006):

> Identity is central to the study of most academic disciplines in universities. Th existence of areas of study such as English, biology, geography or Chinese indicates something of the importance of 'identity' to undergraduate study in the university. When embarking on a course of study, much is assumed, and often has to be assumed for strategic purposes, about the identity of the object being studied. The opening chapters of this book, for instance, begin to explore what it means to **study a degree** whose identity is media and culture. But we can extend the discussion of identity a little further by beginning to ask some questions about identity and identities.

And from Sabine Krajewski, [*The Next Buddha May Be a Community: Practising Intercultural Competence at Macquarie University, Sydney, Australia*](https://books.google.com/books?id=uRArBwAAQBAJ&pg=PR12&dq=%22study+a+degree%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwicn5aTtZPdAhWUITQIHb1vDIgQ6AEILTAB#v=onepage&q=%22study%20a%20degree%22&f=false) (Cambridge Scholars Publishing, 2011):

> If postgraduate students who choose to **study a degree** in International Communication encounter these problems, what does this mean for diverse student groups in other subjects? If it is so difficult to access intercultural communication in a class where awareness and knowledge of theories is a given, where everyone brings in some previous experience and skills in intercultural communication, how can universities equip all students, regardless of their field of study, with the intercultural skills graduates need and are expected to have in a rapidly globalizing world?

The phrase "studied a degree" returns no confirmable relevant matches, but "studying a degree" returns six matches for "studying a degree" and three more for what may be the origin of that phrase, "studying for a degree course." The instances of the latter are interesting in that they suggest that the divergence from normal usage involves not the omission of the preposition *for*, but the use of *studying* in place of, say, *taking*.

Consider this instance from [*Your Professional Qualification: A Guide to Professional Qualifications in the UK– Where They Lead & How to Get Them*](https://books.google.com/books?id=jaJBEsWG_fkC&pg=PA114&dq=%22studying+a+degree%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwir3abzupPdAhXIg1QKHVa-BCQQ6AEIOjAD#v=onepage&q=%22studying%20a%20degree%22&f=false) (Kogan Page Ltd [UK], 2002):

> **Student:** Student members are **studying a degree- or postgraduate-level course** in Landscape Architecture at one of the universities with courses accredited by the Institute.

Here the full implied form of the expression that yields the string "studying a degree" is "studying a degree-level course." In U.S. English, a more normal way to express the same idea might be "taking a undergraduate-level course."

The phrase also occurs in Alasdair Forsyth & Andy ‎Furlong, [*Losing Out?: Socioeconomic Disadvantage and Experience in Further and Higher Education*](https://books.google.com/books?id=u9MwoxLj0bkC&pg=PA45&dq=%22studying+a+degree%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwir3abzupPdAhXIg1QKHVa-BCQQ6AEIXDAJ#v=onepage&q=%22studying%20a%20degree%22&f=false) (Policy Press [UK], 2003):

> "I was doing the HND. Before I left school I didn't realise I was going to come away with as many Highers as I did, so I just applied – I didn't apply for any university courses, I just applied for college. And so once I got there and I realised that I had enough Highers to get me into a university course, I didn't really have as much heart in it {HND} as I thought I would, so I just sort of left at that." (Eleanor, 'returner' {now **studying a Degree course**})

And in Rhena Branch, Mike Bryant & Kate Burton, [*Personal Development All-In-One For Dummies*](https://books.google.com/books?id=DtR7m7-ftbcC&pg=PT237&dq=%22studying+a+degree%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwir3abzupPdAhXIg1QKHVa-BCQQ6AEISTAG#v=onepage&q=%22studying%20a%20degree%22&f=false) (2011):

> You're **studying a degree course** and you fail one module. All-or-nothing thinking makes you decide that the whole endeavour is pointless. Either you get the course totally right or it's just a write-off.

Although the "for Dummies" publishing empire originated in the United States, this book seems to have been written by British authors, to judge from its use of British variant spellings such as *endeavour* and from the fact that its named editor was Gillian Burn, "Founder and Principal of Health Circles Ltd"—a privately held company in Slough.

Matches for "studying a degree that dispense with the clarifying noun *course* go back to this double instance from [*Which Degree?*](https://books.google.com/books?id=vb04AAAAIAAJ&q=%22studying+a+degree%22&dq=%22studying+a+degree%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwir3abzupPdAhXIg1QKHVa-BCQQ6AEIRTAF), volume 5 (Haymarket Publishing [UK], 1985) [combined snippets]:

> The 'why do you want to study this course' question will happen in every interview, so how are you going to field it convincingly? You might consider the options under the following headings:
>
> - reasons for **studying a degree**
> - course content and philosophy
> - flexibility and structure
> - assessment and teaching methods
>
> **Why study a degree?**
>
> You may be totally fascinated by a subject and cannot wait to start studying in depth. Probably you are not particularly worried about the career implications.

The remaining five matches were published during the period from 2006 to 2012. From Jennifer Ross, "[Jean Cassou: Freedom to Compose in Captivity](https://books.google.com/books?id=Dwm86vvwBVkC&pg=PA27&dq=%22studying+a+degree%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwir3abzupPdAhXIg1QKHVa-BCQQ6AEIVjAI#v=onepage&q=%22studying%20a%20degree%22&f=false)," in Nicole Thatcher & ‎Ethel Tolansky, *Six Authors in Captivity: Literary Responses to the Occupation of France During World War II* (Peter Lang [UK], 2006):

> Cassou was born in 1897 in Bilbao, Spain. His mother was Spanish and his father came from the Béarn in France, of Mexican forebears. Throughout his life Cassou remained fiercely loyal to his Spanish origins, **studying a degree** in Spanish at the Sorbonne, developing a deep understanding of Spanish language and culture and forging friendships with the some of the best Spanish writers of the day.

From Jonathan Groucutt, [*Business Degree Success: A Practical Study Guide for Business Students at College and University*](https://books.google.com/books?id=5QcdBQAAQBAJ&pg=PR14&dq=%22studying+a+degree%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwir3abzupPdAhXIg1QKHVa-BCQQ6AEINDAC#v=onepage&q=%22studying%20a%20degree%22&f=false) (Palgrave Macmillan [UK], 2008):

> I have placed particular emphasis of the word 'assume' in the title of this section for a particular reason. As stated in Chapter 2, I suggest that you adopt the mindset of someone in business while undertaking your business degree. I would equally suggest that a student **studying a degree** in music adopt the mindset of a composer and/or performer. Your real aim is to get under the skin of the subject.

From Kaye Kidd, [*They Say I'm Paranoid... and What About Schizophrenia?!*](https://books.google.com/books?id=mmfYTmk0KIgC&pg=PA11&dq=%22studying+a+degree%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwir3abzupPdAhXIg1QKHVa-BCQQ6AEIUTAH#v=onepage&q=%22studying%20a%20degree%22&f=false) (Chipmunka Publishing [UK], 2010):

> I had danced myself silly at University, **studying a degree** in performing arts. I never really wanted to take part in any physical activity; I just became absorbed in reading and writing.

From Julia Dolowicz, [*Writing a UCAS Personal Statement in Seven Easy Steps*](https://books.google.com/books?id=jPHABAAAQBAJ&pg=PT119&dq=%22studying+a+degree%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwir3abzupPdAhXIg1QKHVa-BCQQ6AEIPzAE#v=onepage&q=%22studying%20a%20degree%22&f=false) (How To Books Ltd [UK], 2011):

> **Undergraduate** A student currently **studying a degree**.

And from Simon Whaley, [*The Positively Productive Writer*](https://books.google.com/books?id=FjXtBAAAQBAJ&pg=PA174&dq=%22studying+a+degree%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjdyv6uzpPdAhVqj1QKHbsoAYA4ChDoAQgvMAE#v=onepage&q=%22studying%20a%20degree%22&f=false) (Compass Books [UK], 2012):

> The Open University runs creative writing courses, many of which begin in September. Study takes place using course materials, as well as through online tutor-group conferences. You may also be given the opportunity of corresponding online with other students on the course, or possibly even meeting up at one of the OU's 13 local centres dotted around the UK. Tackling each course can offer you points or credits, which you can then put towards **studying a degree** in a particular aspect of writing or any other subject.

---

***Conclusions***

The phrase "study a degree" may have arisen out of the longer phrase "study a degree-level course" rather than out of "study for a degree." All twelve related matches that a Google Books search turns up come from British publishers, which indicates that the expression has not yet made any appreciable headway in North America. The author of one of the cited texts teaches in Australia, so it's possible that the expression has gained a foothold there.

So, in answer to the posted question, published writers do indeed sometimes say "study [or more often, *studying*] a degree"—but not very frequently and not far from the UK. Whether the level of usage implied by the cited quotations qualifies as "common usage" is difficult for me to tell, but the phrase certainly appears to have become more common in the past fifteen years than it was in the fifteen years before that.

Answer (score 0):

> “Study A Degree.” Really?

Yes, it appears to be fairly common usage.  Below is but one of many examples found nowadays!

> Going back to the Newsnight feature, Pam Tatlow made these points:
>   “There’s not one path to success.”
>   “One size does not fit all.”
>   “There is not one route into success.”
>   You’ll notice these all make the same point. **Tatlow was speaking in terms of whether or not you choose to study a degree.** She’s absolutely right. And the same can be said for students **already studying a degree**.
>
> [The University Blog (UK)](https://theuniversityblog.co.uk/2009/09/03/point-of-studying-a-degree/)